# Why is console output so slow?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista, console-application

So I have noticed this while using a few differnt languages on Windows XP, Vista and 7. If you dump a couple thousand lines a second to the console window it generally has a negative impact on the performance of the system. Computer are fast, and always faster, and the console looks like just some text on a back ground. Where is the bottle neck?

Comment: I think you have answered your own question...

Comment: What platform are you observing this behaviour on. Windows, Unix, Mac . . .?

Comment: It's a fair question, from the standpoint that knowing why updating the text window is slow might provide insight as to whether there's anything that can be done to alleviate the problem, such as attaching the console output stream to some custom window-update logic.

Comment: The bottle neck is in the output ... it has to take some time to print it out (even at an unreadable rate), as opposed to not printing it out. Btw, couple thousand lines a second is a little over the top; a hundred or so at most is what you see when printing it out in a command window.

Comment: In my own limited testing, Windows 7 is at least 10 times slower outputting text to the console than OSX or Linux (and I'm doing this all from the same computer, and Bootcamping Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf) etc has to go from your process with some sort of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to the Console window process (csrss or conhost) The console can also be shared with several processes so there is also some synchronization and buffering going on.

Comment: I follow what your saying in your answer. Do you have any more detail that you can provide?

Comment: @QueueHammer The Windows implementation is undocumented and uses LPC ( http://j00ru.vexillium.org/?p=527 ) WINE also provides some useful information ( https://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/x3423 ). For fun, run "cmd.exe /C dir /S /B c:\" and watch csrss use 50% CPU on a single core 2000/XP system...