# Why is console animation so slow on Windows? (And is there a way to improve speed?)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, console-application

Well I was bored so wanted to make an animation in a console window.

Now when I setup the first bits I noticed it is very slow, something around 333ms for a whole screen to fill with characters..

I am wondering if there is a way to at least get ~20 fps?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

#define WIDTH (100)
#define HEIGHT (35)

bool SetWindow(int Width, int Height) { 
    _COORD coord; 
    coord.X = Width; coord.Y = Height; 

    _SMALL_RECT Rect; 
    Rect.Left = 0;              Rect.Top = 0;  
    Rect.Bottom = Height - 1;   Rect.Right = Width - 1; 

    HANDLE Handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    if (Handle == NULL)return FALSE; 
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(Handle, coord);
    if(!SetConsoleWindowInfo(Handle, TRUE, &Rect)) return FALSE; 
    return TRUE; 
} 

std::array<std::array<unsigned char, WIDTH+1>, HEIGHT> Screen;//WIDTH+1 = prevent cout from undefined behaviour

void Putchars(unsigned char x){
    for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; ++row){
        std::fill(Screen[row].begin(),Screen[row].end(),x);
        Screen[row].at(WIDTH) = 0;//here = prevent cout from undefined behaviour
    }
}

void ShowFrame(DWORD delay = 0,bool fPutchars = false, unsigned char x = 0){
    if(fPutchars)Putchars(x);
    if(delay)Sleep(delay);
    system("CLS");
    for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; ++row)
        std::cout << Screen[row].data() << std::flush;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){//sould execute @~63 fps, yet it executes @~3-4 fps
    if(SetWindow(100,HEIGHT)){
        for(unsigned char i = 219; i != 0; --i)
        ShowFrame(16,true, i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: after reading numerous answers, tips and comments I finally worked it out, thank you guys, this is my final "base" code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

#define WIDTH (100)
#define HEIGHT (34)

HANDLE current;
HANDLE buffer;

bool SetWindow(int Width, int Height) { 
    _COORD coord; 
    coord.X = Width; coord.Y = Height; 

    _SMALL_RECT Rect; 
    Rect.Left = 0;              Rect.Top = 0;  
    Rect.Bottom = Height - 1;   Rect.Right = Width - 1; 

    HANDLE Handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    if (Handle == NULL)return FALSE; 
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(Handle, coord);
    if(!SetConsoleWindowInfo(Handle, TRUE, &Rect)) return FALSE; 
    return TRUE; 
} 

std::array<std::array<CHAR, WIDTH+1>, HEIGHT> Screen;//WIDTH+1 = prevent cout from undefined behaviour

void Putchars(CHAR x){
    for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; ++row){
        std::fill(Screen[row].begin(),Screen[row].end(),x);
        Screen[row].at(WIDTH) = 0;//here = prevent cout from undefined behaviour
    }
}

void ShowFrame(DWORD delay = 0, bool fPutchars = false, CHAR x = 0){
    if(fPutchars)Putchars(x);
    if(delay)Sleep(delay);
    //system("CLS");
    _COORD coord;
    coord.X = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; ++row)
    {
        coord.Y = row;
        FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(buffer,Screen[row].data()[0],100,coord,NULL);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){//sould execute @~63 fps, yet it executes @~3-4 fps
    SetWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    current = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    buffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer (
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
        NULL
    );
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer (buffer);

    if(SetWindow(WIDTH,HEIGHT)){
        for(CHAR i = 219; i != 0; --i)
        ShowFrame(250,true, i);
    }
    CloseHandle (buffer); //clean up
    return 0;
}
```

and it seems to work very fast :)

Comment: The Windows console *is* indeed very slow compared to e.g. putty. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404551/why-is-console-output-so-slow. (Not a duplicate - it asks *why* not *how to fix it*)

Comment: use the console functions (i think i said that before, so y not done it?)

Comment: so a lot of sychronization.. and what about disabling that sychronization?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf *which* functions? :o what console functions? xD

Comment: u now, google ["console functions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=console+functions). o clang i did that for you. but anyway

Comment: ok gimme a few h to study all of the functions, what they do and if they are usable for me : P

Comment: +1 for updating the question to include the answers.

Comment: How many FPS have you got?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just glancing at your code, you're spawning a separate program ("CLS") once per frame. That's *horrendously* slow all by itself.

Contrary to some of the comments, the Windows console is capable of at least *fairly* reasonable speed if used even close to correctly (as in: you can update the console faster than any monitor can display the data).

Just for reference, here's a version of John Conway's Game of Life written for the Windows console. For timing purposes, it just generates a random starting screen and runs for 2000 generations, then stops. On my machine, it does 2000 generations in about 2 seconds, or around 1000 frames per second (useless, since a typical monitor can only update at around 60-120 Hz). Under 32-bit Windows with a full-screen console, it can roughly double that (again, at least on my machine). I'm pretty sure with a little work, this could be sped up some more, but I've never seen any reason to bother.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <io.h>

#define     ROWS        50
#define     COLS        80

// The total number of generations is really double this number.
int generations = 1000;

int civ1[ROWS+2][COLS+2], civ2[ROWS+2][COLS+2];

CHAR_INFO disp[ROWS][COLS];
HANDLE console;
COORD size = { COLS, ROWS };
COORD src = { 0, 0};
SMALL_RECT  dest = { 0, 0, COLS, ROWS };

void ClrScrn(char attrib) {
    COORD pos = { 0, 0};
    DWORD written;
    unsigned size;

    size = ROWS * COLS;

    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(console, ' ', size, pos, &written);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(console, attrib, size, pos, &written);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, pos);
}

void fill_edges(int civ1[ROWS+2][COLS+2]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i=1; i<=ROWS; ++i) {
        civ1[i][0] = civ1[i][COLS];
        civ1[i][COLS+1] = civ1[i][1];
    }
    for (j=1; j<=COLS; ++j) {
        civ1[0][j] = civ1[ROWS][j];
        civ1[ROWS+1][j] = civ1[1][j];
    }
    civ1[0][0] = civ1[ROWS][COLS];
    civ1[ROWS+1][COLS+1] = civ1[1][1];
    civ1[0][COLS+1] = civ1[ROWS][1];
    civ1[ROWS+1][0] = civ1[1][COLS];
}

void update_generation(int old_gen[ROWS+2][COLS+2], 
                       int new_gen[ROWS+2][COLS+2])
{
    int i, j, count;

    for (i = 1; i <= ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= COLS; ++j)
        {
            count = old_gen[i - 1][j - 1] +
                old_gen[i - 1][j] +
                old_gen[i - 1][j + 1] +
                old_gen[i][j - 1] +
                old_gen[i][j + 1] +
                old_gen[i + 1][j - 1] +
                old_gen[i + 1][j] +
                old_gen[i + 1][j + 1];

            switch(count) 
            {
            case 2:
                new_gen[i][j] = old_gen[i][j];
                break;

            case 3:
                new_gen[i][j] = 1;
                disp[i-1][j-1].Char.AsciiChar = '*';
                break;
            default:
                new_gen[i][j] = 0;
                disp[i-1][j-1].Char.AsciiChar = ' ';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    WriteConsoleOutput(console, (CHAR_INFO *)disp, size, src, &dest);
    fill_edges(new_gen);
}

void initialize(void)
{
    int i, j;

    ClrScrn(0x71);
    srand(((unsigned int)time(NULL))|1);

    for (i = 1; i <= ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= COLS; ++j)
        {
            civ1[i][j] = (int)(((__int64)rand()*2)/RAND_MAX);
            disp[i-1][j-1].Char.AsciiChar = civ1[i][j] ? '*' : ' ';
            disp[i-1][j-1].Attributes = 0x71;
        }
    }
    WriteConsoleOutput(console, (CHAR_INFO *)disp, size, src, &dest);
    fill_edges(civ1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;

    if ( argc != 1)
        generations = atoi(argv[1]);

    console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    initialize();
    for (i = 0; i <generations; ++i)
    {
        update_generation(civ1, civ2);
        update_generation(civ2, civ1);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If nothing else, this has a `ClrScrn` function you may find handy.

Comment: As a side note, WriteConsoleOutput can be extremely slow if outputting data with frequent attribute changes. Painting full screen of characters with constant attribute e.g 0x0071 results in >150fps. Doing same where attributes are random 0x0000-0x00FF brings windows to its knees at 5fps !!! (Win7 here)

Answer (score 9):

Do not use cout to write to console. Use the WriteConsole from console API instead. And you can use double buffering like in normal graphical animations with SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073.aspx

Also don't use system ("cls") to clear the screen, FillConsoleOutputCharacter is a lot faster.

Comment: +1 for suggesting [`SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686010.aspx) for double buffering.

Comment: You might want to benchmark before giving a +1 for SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(). This (SLOW) function really makes more sense for saving/restoring screen contents. For example, a file viewing program might switch to a clean buffer, do display, then restore previous. Key to console speed is not double buffering, but reducing # of calls to console I/O functions, since each costs a local procedure call which represents the lion's share of console slowness.