# Difference in execution time in Windows shell and Git bash shell on windows 7

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, algorithm, operating-system

I have a sample code to optimize

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

template<typename NumType=float>
void RenderSphereOnScreen(const NumType* const _coords)
{
   std::cout<<_coords[0]<<" "<<_coords[1]<<" "<<_coords[2]<<std::endl; //assume
}

template<typename NumType>
class SphereRenderTask
{
    NumType  _coords[3];
    public:
 SphereRenderTask(const NumType& x, const NumType& y, const NumType& z)
{
    if(std::is_same<NumType, int>::value || std::is_same<NumType, float>::value || std::is_same<NumType, double>::value)
    {
        _coords[0] = x;
        _coords[1] = y;
        _coords[2] = z;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error.unknown class type!!\n";
        assert(0);
    }
}
 void operator()() const
 {
    RenderSphereOnScreen(_coords);
 }
};

std::vector<SphereRenderTask<double>*> taskList;
const int THREADS = 3;
void *renderThread(void *index)
{
    int tid = *((int *)index);
    int max = -1;
    int i = tid*(taskList.size()/THREADS);
    max = (tid+1)*(taskList.size()/THREADS);

    for( std::vector<SphereRenderTask<double>*>::iterator iter=taskList.begin() + i; i<max;)
    {
        (**iter)();
        i++;
        iter++;
    }

}

void StartRendering(const char* const inputFilePath)
{
    void sequential_render();
    void multithreaded_render();
   taskList.clear(); //init
   std::ifstream inputfile(inputFilePath);

   double x,y,z;

   while (inputfile >> x >> y>> z)
   {
     taskList.push_back(new SphereRenderTask<double>(x,y,z));
   }
    int y1 = taskList.size();
    inputfile.close();



    if(!THREADS)
        sequential_render();
    else
        multithreaded_render();
}

void sequential_render()
{
    for(std::vector<SphereRenderTask<double>*>::iterator iter=taskList.begin(); iter!=taskList.end(); ++iter)
    {
       (**iter)();
    }
}
void multithreaded_render()
{
    pthread_t tid[THREADS];
    for(int i=0;i<THREADS;i++)
    {
       int tmp = i;
       pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, renderThread, &tmp);
       pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    StartRendering("sphere.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

what this does:

1. reads a file name "sphere.txt" which contains 100k lines of (x,y,z) which could be float

   Example:

   ```
    136 562 293
    629 399 497
    682 642 995
    739 351 869
    607 968 7
    262 788 863
   ....
   ```

   so on up to 100k lines
2. save those in a data structure , taskList pointer vector
3. then display in screen using either sequential_render or multithreaded_render

I have two questions regarding this:

1. running this gives diff run time on windows shell and git bash shell , both on windows.(compiler mingw g++ 5.1.0)

   windows shell:

   [image]

   git bash shell

   [image]
2. why does using multithreading doesn't improve running time? I have tried this both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Your "multithreaded" version starts one thread and waits for it to complete, then it starts the next thread and waits for that to complete, then it starts the next thread...

Comment: You're mostly measuring the time it takes to print things in the console, and Windows' cmd is notoriously slow.

Comment: I doubt printing to `std::cout` from multiple thread will be usefull. The output from the different threads will most likely get mixed up. Unless you synchronize them, but then only one thread can work at any time, so your effectively back to a single thread.

Comment: One problem you will encounter once you're actually running several threads concurrently is that you pass `&tmp` to the thread, and `tmp`'s lifetime might have ended by the time the thread starts.

Comment: In Windows some terminal processes are extremely slow. I remember a Meteor project. It was faster to start a Linux in a Virtual Box and build inside the Virtual Box than to build in Windows without running a Virtual Box in the background. Now I learned that I probably could also use a Git Bash Shell instead of PowerShell or Windows Cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some small conclusion here:

1. It just is that way. CMD *is* horribly slow. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404551/why-is-console-output-so-slow) explains it a bit and provides some links that may be interesting.
2. You don't actually have multithreading:

   ```
   pthread_t tid[THREADS]; // Array of threads

   for(int i=0;i<THREADS;i++)
   {
       int tmp = i;
       pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, renderThread, &tmp); // Create one thread
       pthread_join(tid[i], NULL); // wait for it to complete
   }
   ```

   So how many threads are working at any given time? Right, only one. So the basic time for printing elements stays the same as in the single-threaded version, but creating and joining a thread takes time that is not required in the single-threaded version. Correct use of multi threading would be:

   ```
   pthread_t tid[THREADS]; // Array of threads
   int tmps[THREADS]; // each thread wants it's own tmp

   //start all the threads
   for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
   {
       tmps[i] = i;
       pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, renderThread, &tmps[i]);
   }

   // join them all
   for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
   {
       pthread_join(tid[i], NULL); // wait for it to complete
   }
   ```

But as I already mentioned in my comment, writing to `std::cout` from multiple threads will only mix up the lines. Also writing to anything usually requires some synchronisation, so most of the time your threads will just wait. Doesn't seem usefull to use threading here.